# jq dividing a single string value into two

Tags: json, jq

```
[
{
  "host": "a.com",
  "ip": "1.2.2.3",
  "port": 8,
  "name":"xyz", 
  "info":"part1    part2    part3    part4"
},
{
  "host": "b.com",
  "ip": "2.5.0.4",
  "port": 3,
  "name":"xyz",
  "info":"part1    part2    part3    part4"
},
{
  "host": "c.com",
  "ip": "9.17.6.7",
  "port": 4,
  "name":"xyz",
   "info":"part1    part2    part3    part4"
}
]
```

I want to produce output in the following format:

```
a.com,1.2.2.3,part1,part
b.com,2.5.0.4,part1,par2
c.com,9.17.6.7,part1,part2
```

The problem is the key `"info`" is a single key, but I want to divide two pieces of information separated by tab separately. How to do this?

This is my jq command to parse the file:

```
cat input.json | jq -r '.[] | "\(.host),\(.ip),\(.info)"' > result.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `info` value is seperated by four-spaces, not by tabs because raw tab character is not allowed in JSON and jq raises an error when there is an invalid character in input. If I'm not wrong, this command should do what you want

```bash
jq -r '.[] | (.info | split("    ")[0:2] | join(",")) as $info | "\(.host),\(.ip),\($info)"' input.json > result.txt
```